# STM32: Booting and fetching vector table from SRAM

Tags: stm32, openocd

I would like to run my program from the SRAM region of the device.

It seemed quite clear to me, that I have to perform following steps:

1. Modify the vector table offset register `SCB->VTOR` (located at `0xE000ED08`) to point to the beginning of the SRAM region, as that is where my vector table is located: `0x20000000`
2. Reset the device so it fetches the stack pointer initialization value and the reset handler adress again.

Unfortunately, whenever I issue a `reset init` command in OpenOCD, the value of `SCB->VTOR` gets cleared. Hence, stack pointer initialization value and reset handler adress are fetched from `0x00000000` instead of `0x20000000`.

---

### Question

How do I get my STM32F4 to fetch the vector table from `0x20000000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load the `SP` (MSP) from `0x20000000` (=VTOR) and the `PC` from `0x20000004` (=VTOR+4) manually.

The `reset init` command will usually reset the whole chip and no just the core - and `VTOR` will be initialized to zero even then.